# Intel XDK page navigation

Tags: html

I recently started creating a website with Intel XDK and I found out I couldn't navigate between pages. Is there any way to go about this? I just want to link all the pages on my navigation bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add id for each navigation section and use the following to navigate as you like,

```
$("#yournavid").click(function() {
       window.location.href = "yournavigationpage.html";
    });
```

or simply add

```
href="yournavigationpage.html"
```

on navigation section in HTML itself

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in navigation control in templates like the List View or Side-by-Side menu.

Here is an example of list View template. In most of the cases you use the 'Go back' button to the page you are in to go back to where you came from.
http://hodentekmobile.blogspot.com/2014/09/creating-projects-with-intel-xdk.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with the Designer, you should have an index_user_script.js file. That file manages all the triggers for changing pages. There, you just place that:

```
$(document).on("click", "#yourIdname", function(evt)
{ 
     //IF IT IS  A PAGE YOU SHOULD USE ACTIVATE_PAGE
     activate_page("#mainpage");

     //IF IT IS  A SUBPAGE YOU SHOULD USE ACTIVATE_PAGE
     activate_subpage("#inicio");         
});
```